# KeepassX & YubiKey - cannot open database created with KeePass

Tags: lubuntu, yubikey, keepassx

In earlier versions of Ubuntu and KeePass I used to run KeePass with `wine`, but in the latest versions, the YubiKey is not detected in the `wine`environment ("error connecting to yubikey"). No problem, I thought: Let's use `keepassx`. Seems not that easy, though...

I followed this [comprehensive manual](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/keepassx-2-yubikey-support/) to install KeePassX with challenge response 2-factor support for linux (ubuntu/lubuntu). The repository `ppa:hda-me/keepassx2-yubico` for `eoan` is not yet available, but using `bionic` instead seems to work quite fine. At least on the first glance.

Now I face two issues, and have no more idea how to solve them:

1. The challenge response option was available after the first startup, but the (definitively correct) password together with the YubiKey response did not work to open a KeePass database created under Windows.

Therefore, my first question is: Is the encryption of KeePassX incompatible with that from KeePass, when using a challenge response as second factor?

2. Now, after some restarting and updating, the "challenge response" option is disabled (gray) and I lack any idea why. I am quite sure that `keepassx` was installed from the right repository.

My second question: Any idea why the option is disabled and how to enable it?

[image]

[image]

**Update:** When running `keepassx` from the console, the "challenge response" option is available. But not, when running `KeePassX` from the start menu. The correct combination of password and key response still results in "wrong key or file damaged". With the windows KeePass, the file can still be opened.

Comment: You could try with an alternate implementation: KeepassXC. The Changelog tells there's support for challenge response. You'd probably need at least 2.3.0 (https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/wiki/KeePassXC-Changelog#230-2018-02-27)

Comment: Unfortunately, KeepassXC has the same issue: The password + YubiKey working with the Windows version of KeePass does not work with the Linux version :(

Comment: considering this random searched link where it works: https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=2155 I think your issue is with the Yubikey setup on Linux rather than on Keepass. I don't have the hardware, so can't help much more

Comment: Okay, it seems that KeePassXC handles YubiKey integration different than the Windows KeePass. KeePassXC requires the challenge/response every time is saves the database, and it also changes the underlying key (says the website about whether this is true 2-factor security). The Windows version, on the other hand, creates a XML file required for decryption. Solution: KeePassXC for Windows and Linux. Seems to work so far :)